# Pointer to const and following modification via dereferencing

Tags: pointers, memory

What is the key point to understand this?

```
    const float x = 4.5;
    float *ptr = &x;
    *ptr = 5.5;
    
    printf("%f\n", *ptr); 5.500000
    printf("%f\n", x); 4.500000
    printf("%i\n", ptr); 1805923228
    printf("%i\n", &x); 1805923228
```